# Bluetooth raw byte data transfer for cordova

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, data-transfer

How do I send and receive series of data Bytes between a bluetooth device and Android/iOS in Cordova?

The details of my project:

I have a bluetooth sensor device that I am developing.  The device sends data as a series of bytes.  It also uses a binary control word system for the device API and sends/receives commands as series of bytes.  So I need to receive and send unsigned bytes (8-bit values, 0-255).  This setup was easy use in Java and Arduino.  I have working computer and arduino apps communicating with the device using a simple serial connection.

Now I am developing a mobile app using Cordova, Angular, Ionic, and the bluetoothSerial plugin (excellent work by Don Coleman)[github here](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial).  The app must run on android and iOS.

UPDATE: More Details, and The Answer:
Sanfor pointed out that bluetoothSerial has a write() method that takes Uint8Array.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but I cannot get this method to work!  Here is what I tried:

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(2);
var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
view[0] = 0;
view[1] = 200;

//write(view); // does not work either
// re: 123,101,100,123,34,101,149,189,201,137,149,189,201,149,153,149,101,149,189,201,255
//write(buf);  // does not work
// re: 65,97,77,101,115,77,103,101,115,103,61,101,115,61
writeBuffer(buf); // does work - thanks to Glen Arrowsmith!
// correct response: 0,101,100,0,200,101,100,200
```

Also, attempts to use bluetoothSerial.read could be forced to work for 7-bit numbers.  There are variations using Uint8Arrays, but they just change how the data receipt fails because the inBuffer is converted to String inside bluetoothSerial.  :

```
bluetoothSerial.read(readSuccess, simpleLog); // does not work
function readSuccess ( data ) {       
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
        arr.push(data.charCodeAt(i));
    } // returned data is corrupted for all values over 127!
    console.log('Converted ' + arr3 + ' with length ' + arr3.length);
  }
```

THE ANSWER:
I found Glen Arrowsmith's fork of bluetoothSerial [github](https://github.com/garrows/BluetoothSerial) with added readBuffer and writeBuffer (works in the code above).  However, I've noticed that writeBuffer(buf) doesn't work properly for arrays longer than 2-3 elements!  Is this a timing issue?  It's possible it's on the device side.  For now I've got an $interval setup to send out bytes of a larger array working.

I was also able to get reading working, though only after some work (the cast to Uint8Array) to get the Bytes back out in proper form:

```
bluetoothSerial.readBuffer(readSuccess, simpleLog);
function readSuccess ( data ) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(data);
    var msg = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        msg += arr[i]+', ';
    }
    console.log('Received ' +arr+' with vals '+msg+'and length '+arr.length);
    cb(arr);
}
```

UPDATE 2:  I seem to have answered my own question by finding a forked version of bluetoothSerial and then adding in the above modifications to the output.  I'll update if anybody suggests a cleaner method.

Comment: can you share the whole working code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have everything you need, so maybe I didn't quite understand you correctly. I assume you want to see how to handle the sending of bytes with that plugin, right? For examples you can see the plugin provider's [examples](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/tree/master/examples). Also I would mention that the [bluetoothSerial.write](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial#write) can handle [UInt8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) as it's parameter. In JavaScript

> The Uint8Array typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers.

which I suppose is just what you want.

Comment: The LED example does show how to receive data using the subscriber, which I may end up doing.  I see what you mean about write() documentation saying it can send Bytes, but I can't yet get write() to send useful data...I've added more info and code above.

Comment: @brendan: Please don't change the question once written as it partially invalidates the original answer given. If your question is now only that are you doing it right, I'd say it looks just what I could be writing so yes.

Comment: I've undone any changes in the original question, and instead just added the solution I've got working currently.  Thanks for the pointer.